# how to update row time in sequence

Tags: sql-server

I have below table

```
userid,    date,   starttime, endtime, taskid
1      2023/08/05   07:00  20:00 ,      1
1      2023/08/05   17:00  23:00 ,      2
1      2023/08/06   17:00  23:00 ,      1
1      2023/08/07   05:00  10:00 ,      1
1      2023/08/07   13:00  20:00 ,      2
1      2023/08/07   18:00  23:00 ,      3
```

Now what I want to do is I want to have one row for date 2023/08/05 starttime and endtime like
07:00 to 23:00, because user is working for me.. but assign different task... but I can do total by 13:00 to 23:00 ..
and for the
2023/05/08 we need to have two rows like **05:00 to 10:00 and 13:23**, because he does have task between 10:00 to 13:00
I have tried

```
select userid, datediff(minute, min(starttime), max(enddate)) 
from   shifts 
group by date
```

but this causing issue of 2023/05/08 and calculating 05:00 to 10:00 which should not needed..
I need output like

```
userid ,date ,starttime, endtime
    1     2023/08/05 07:00    23:00
    1     2023/08/06  17:00   23:00
    1     2023/08/07  05:00   10:00
    1     2023/08/07  13:00    23:00
```

can you please give sql query to do this

Comment: No, I am not getting your outout.Rexplain the logic of your output to get better answer.Explain all the 4 output

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify the rows where you want to group it as one. This is achive by using `LAG()` and cumulative `sum() over (...)`

First use `LAG()` window function to get previous row `endtime` and compare with current row's `starttime` to determine if it should be group under same group. After that perform a cumulative sum on the flag `f` to gives you the required group `grp`

```
with
cte as
(
  select userid, shiftdate, starttime, endtime, 
         prev_endtime = lag(endtime) over (partition by userid, shiftdate 
                                                 order by starttime)
  from   shifts
),
cte2 as
(
  select userid, shiftdate, starttime, endtime, 
         f = case when starttime > prev_endtime
                  then 1
                  else 0
                  end
  from   cte
),
cte3 as
(
  select userid, shiftdate, starttime, endtime, 
         grp = sum(f) over (partition by userid, shiftdate order by starttime)
  from   cte2
)
select userid, shiftdate, 
       starttime = min(starttime),
       endtime   = max(endtime)
from   cte3
group by userid, shiftdate, grp;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/2tM3rTDf)

Note that you have tag multiple version of `SQL Server` including those that is out of support. The above query does not work for `SQL Server 2008` as it does not support `sum() over ( order by ...)`